# Quantifying the level of hoppiness in a beer

Tags: beer, hops, flavor, calculations

Does anyone know of some sort of measurement for the hoppiness of a beer?  Late hop additions don't add much to the bitterness (IBUs) but they can add tons of hop flavor.  Is there some way to quantify this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there currently is no scale to quantify and measure the amount of hop flavor and aroma in beer.

Essential hop oils in beer provide this hoppy flavor and aroma, so you might think that if the amount of essential hop oil in beer could be accurately measured, then such a scale for non-bitter hop quantity would exist.  However, chemists have not yet identified such a relationship.

There are plenty of articles that discuss this in more detail, such as [this](http://www.brewingtechniques.com/library/backissues/issue2.1/tinseth.html) one.

What this means for the homebrewer is that your only available gauge is experience sampling brews in which you know the hop schedule.